# Reset Variable Value to Original Value? (Ruby) (CLOSED)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I want to make a counter that will reset to 0 if something happens.  It would look vaguely like this:

counter = 0

if *something happens*

```
counter += 1
```

elsif *something else happens*

```
*counter is set back to 0*
```

end

Thanks so much!

**EDIT**

```
 def attack(cookie)
      cookie.changeDefense()
      @offense = Random.new.rand(0..100)
      win_count = 0
      puts "#{cookie.name}'s health is #{cookie.health}"
      puts "The foe's health is #{@health}"
      puts win_count
       puts "Do you want to fight?"
       response = gets.chomp
       if response == "yes"
           if @offense > cookie.defense
               cookie.health -= 10
               puts "The foe has defeated you!"
               win_count += 1
           else
               puts "You win!  The foe has lost health!"
               @health -= 10
               win_count = 0
               number = Random.new.rand(0..100)
                    if number.between?(15, 50)
                        puts "The enemy has dropped a health item!"
                        cookie.health += 5
                    elsif number.between?(60, 95)
                        puts "The enemy has dropped a fighting upgrade!  You 
have a hightened chance of winning!"
                        cookie.lowDefense += 10
                    else

                end
       end
```

This is the code, it is from a text based game so there is more than just the counter there.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I have solved it by using global variables in parts of the code not shown here, the question cannot be deleted but no more assistance is needed.  Thank you!

Comment: Just a regular assignment `c = 0` should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

just put `elseif ("something else happens"){
counter = 0
}

this should make counter equal 0 again

Comment: every time the code loops again, it resets it to zero at the top no matter what (this is in a loop), how can I fix that?

Comment: well if you have  counter = 0 at the end of the loop it will be set to 0 at the begging so just remove counter = 0 at the end of the loop. I'm having a hard time understanding if you could post the code it would help a lot!

Comment: its part of a huge bit of code so I will take the chunk and simplify it and post it in a minute

Comment: just post the loop?

Comment: else
               puts "You win!  The foe has lost health!"
               @health -= 10
               win_count = 0
               number = Random.new.rand(0..100) is it that part you need help with or wich part is it?

Comment: no, I want the win_count to not reset to 0 at the top every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

make the win_count = 0 in `else
               puts "You win!  The foe has lost health!"
               @health -= 10
               win_count = 0` 
Part to win_count -= 1

Comment: so define win_count in the else?

Comment: make it so i take away 1 instead of seting in to 0 and yes in the else part

Comment: that takes away the functionality of what I originally wanted however

Comment: else if  win_count < 0   win_count = 0